# jQuery Scroll: prevent anchor text from appearing in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-click-event

So i got the jQuery scroll working just fine on my page.
But I want to change one thing.
I don't want to show the anchor text in the url. ie. #products or #contactinfo

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div>
<a href="#products">Products</a>
<a href="#contactinfo">Contact info</a>
</div>

<div id="products"></div>

<div id="contactinfo"></div>
```

**jQuery code:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: long shot but have you tried to change it to  $('a[href^="#"]') ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span class="link" rel="#products">Products</span>
    <span class="link" rel="#contactinfo">Contact info</span>
</div>

<div style="height:800px;"></div>
<div id="products">products</div>
<div style="height:800px;"></div>
<div id="contactinfo">contact</div>
<div style="height:800px;"></div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.link').on('click',function (e) {
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $($(this).attr('rel')).offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {});
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekjain/rDYs9/1/)

Answer (score 1):

just add a `return false;` at the end of the `click` function.
Edit: and probalby remove this line, I mean.. it does exactly what you not want? Appearently?

```
window.location.hash = target;
```

Comment: for me it works, cant test the hash url though since its an iframe

Comment: For me it doesn't change anything adding the return false; and removing window.location.hash = target;

Comment: @Alex Haha, actually just noticed mine didn't work because jQuery was not being used :D